# <text> in svg file is not rendering in react-native component using react-native-svg-uri

Tags: svg, react-native

I have a csv file which has  as below. I have used react-native-svg-uri to render csv file however for some reason only  is not  rendering. Other part of csv file is rendering fine.

Following is  excerpt from csv file.

```
<text id="PAY" font-family="BentonSans-Bold, BentonSans" font-size="20" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="38" fill="#1274B8">
    <tspan x="87" y="34">PAY</tspan>
</text>
```

Following is react-native code.

```
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';

<View>
        <SvgUri source={require('./logo.svg')} />
</View>
```

Is css used in  cause problem? How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the source of `react-native-svg-uri` here: https://github.com/matc4/react-native-svg-uri/blob/master/index.js#L90

It doesn't have a case for `<Text />`. To fix you'd have to fork and add a case for it :)